# How to look up lost iTunes shared library password?

Tags: itunes, password, keychain, home-sharing

I forgot the password to my iTunes home shared library. I know I can set a new password in the iTunes prefs, but I do not want to update all my home devices to the new password! I cannot find the password in the keychain either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Home-sharing password is your Apple ID password. It should exist in your keychain:

1. Type **Keychain Access** in Spotlight. It should appear in the drop down menu. Open it.
2. Select your **Login Keychain**
3. Type in **iTunes Store Password** in the search bar of Keychain access.
4. Double click it and tick "Show Password"

If this appears:

[image]

Type in your user account password and click allow. You should then see your Apple ID password in plaintext.

Comment: Whether or not the sharing user is an admin or not is irrelevant. The method of retrieving the password from Keychain Access works equally well for non-admin accounts, and you never need to type a separate admin password.

Comment: "Your Home-sharing password is your Apple ID password." -- This was the missing information!